# C++ exception catching

Tags: c++, exception, exit

After a successful catch , does the function that caught the exception exit ?
For example :

```
      foo()
       {
         try
        {
           valid(name, name1, name2, name3, name3);
        }
        catch (int error)
        {
           std::cout << "Error number :" << error << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Valid names" << std::endl;
       }
```

If I catch an exception , will "Valid names" be printed ?

Comment: What about simply trzing out? What actually hinders you to do so?

Comment: Simply type into your compiler, build, and run.

Comment: Look here: [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Your question has been pasted into the magic answer machine](http://ideone.com/fiz8Va)

Comment: @Noam Sorry typo: _trying_ (I've got a weird kezboard :-) )

Comment: @DrewDormann thank you . I was not sure how to check this .

Comment: You're getting down votes because all you have to do it put the code you wrote here into your compiler, run it and see what happens. Here are some good books: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Galik , sorry , I will delete this question .

Comment: @Noam _"I will delete this question "_ I'm afraid you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A caught exception will continue after the catch block provided you have not exited in the catch block once the commands in the catch block are finished.

The answer to your question is yes.